# Set transform from another GameObject's script

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, unityscript, gameobject

I'm trying to make a script to set an object when is being instantiated. The problem is, I don't clearly know how to do it. I have this function..

```
function spawnPlayer()
{
    var CameraScript = GameObject.Find(PlayerPrefab.name).GetComponent("Camera Control");
    Network.Instantiate(PlayerPrefab, spawnObject.position, Quaternion.identity, 0);
}
```

Where PlayerPrefab is going to be the Prefab that's going to be instantiated. When this happens, I need to set the instantiated gameObject on another GameObject which is camera and has a script called "Camera Control" and inside there's a transform Target which I'm trying to set. How to do this?

Comment: Is your game really multiplayer, or is `Network.Instantiate` a typo?

Comment: I can't even understand what you are having trouble with sorry.

Answer (score 21):

The code you posted can't be right. You are using the PlayerPrefab's name to to find the Camera Control script attached to the camera? By that logic then the moment you instantiate `PlayerPrefab`, on the second line, you will have a second camera.

I think what you want to do is this: **Instantiate the player prefab and make the camera point to the player**.

So I am assuming the `CameraControl` script is created. You need the following before we start to code.

1. Attach `CameraControl` script to the camera in the scene.

   [image]
2. Make sure the `Player` script is attached to the Player Prefab.

   [image]
3. Have a third script that will instantiate the PlayerPrefab. I will call it `Instantiator`. Attach it to an empty GameObject in the scene, think of it as the world GameObject. We will call it World.
4. Make sure the `Instantiator` script is attached to the World GameObject and that it is pointing to the PlayerPrefab.

   [image]

---

### Code: Instantiator

The `Instantiator` script will spawn and create things we will use in the scene.

```c#
 #pragma strict

var PlayerPrefab : GameObject;

function Start () 
{
    // You can add position and rotation to the function call if you like.
    var p = Instantiate(PlayerPrefab) as GameObject;

    // Find the camera script and point to Player's transform.
    Camera.main.GetComponent("CameraControl").SendMessage("setTarget", p.transform);
}
```

Notice I used the fact that the MainCamera in the scene is marked by Unity for you so it is easy to find.

---

### Code: CameraControl

The `CameraControl` will have the logic to follow the Player as you see fit. Notice that target will point to what the camera will focus on. Of course following the Player around you will have to write.

```c#
var target : Transform;

function setTarget(t : Transform)
{
    target = t;
}
```

---

*I just taught myself a bit of JavaScript. I had never used it before.*

Answer (score 2):

I found my solution.

What I was meaning on my question was to set my camera's script the transform of the instantiated object.

I did not have to make many empty objects with scripts value of each object; it took me hours to find it because I did not know how unity handles the scripts objects calls.

This is how I made it:

```
var PlayerPrefab : GameObject;
var spawnObject : Transform;
private var MainCamera : GameObject;

function spawnPlayer()
{
    var player = Instantiate(PlayerPrefab, spawnObject.position, Quaternion.identity);
    MainCamera = GameObject.Find("MainCamera");

    player.name = "Ball";

    if(MainCamera)
    {
        MainCamera.GetComponent.<CameraControl>().target = player.transform;
        Debug.Log("Succeed.");
    }
}
```

Like this, my camera will have the transform properties of the new instantiated object automatically.

Comment: You do realize that is the same thing I posted right?

Comment: It seems to be different insofar as the code is using different functions or a different order and the explanation text is different. Probably no bad intent.

Comment: You should either accept your own or the solution from FunctionR, so that the question gets an accepted answer, because otherwise it will remain in the no accepted answer list...